# LinkedList only adds two elements in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to learn linkedlist in c++, I am facing a problem as linkedlist is only adding 2 elements.

code:

```
struct Node {
int data1;
Node* next;
};

void firstElement(Node *&head, int d)
{
Node* temp = new Node;
temp->data1 = d;
temp->next = NULL;
head = temp;
}

void insert(Node *&node, int data)
{
Node* temp = new Node;
temp->data1 = data;
temp->next = NULL;


while(node)
{
    if(node->next == NULL)
    {
        node->next = temp;
        return;
    }
    node = node->next;
}

}

void display(Node *&node)
{
while(node != NULL)
{
    cout << node->data1 << endl;
    node = node->next;
}
}

int main()
{
Node* head;

firstElement(head, 1);
insert(head, 2);
insert(head, 3);
insert(head, 4);
insert(head, 5);
insert(head, 6);
insert(head, 7);
insert(head, 8);
insert(head, 9);
insert(head, 10);

display(head);

}
```

In the output, it only gives me value `9 and 10` i.e only the last 2 elements. Looks like it's just replacing the values. However, I am not getting it. For my `temp` node I am already initializing it to next i.e `temp->next = NULL`.
And in `insert()` function, i am using an `if condition` to only add next node if its NULL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through yout code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: I haven't used c++ for years but is "*&" really correct in this case?

Comment: @StefanAgartsson It just takes a reference to a pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from `insert` function. It takes a `Node* &` so as soon as you do

```
node = node->next;
```

in the loop, it will modify the variable used by caller as the node parameter list.
Remove `&` and your problem is solved :

```
void insert(Node* node, int data)
```

Comment: Recommend changing "original list" to "variable used by caller as the `node` parameter" for additional clarity.

Comment: Yep. it worked. and if it add `*&` then I had to pass that parameterized node to a new node, and then add temp to that new node e.g `Node* n = node; while(n) ...... n->next = temp; .... n = n->next;` 
But I didn't understand as you said, it will modify the original list. If it was replacing the original shouldn't it then only show me 10? why `9 and 10`?